# Django save method overwritten and type object 'cursos' has no attribute 'object'

Tags: python, django, django-models, attributeerror

I am new to django and I 'm trying to create a code of course to use it later to generate another code in another table.

I have overwritten the method save but I returns an error

```
Exception Value:    
type object 'cursos' has no attribute 'object'
```

According to other responses the problem is that my codigo_curso not being filled yet but as in the example of the field slug does not require to be filled field after being recorded in the database

```
import re
from django.db import models
from django.utils.text import slugify

# Create your models here.
class cursos(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, blank=False)
    descripcion = models.TextField(null=False, blank=True)
    creado = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    modificado = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(editable=False)
    codigo_curso = models.CharField(max_length=4, null=False, blank=True, editable=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
       return u'%s' % (self.nombre,)

    def crear_codigo(self):
       curso_nombre = str(cursos.object.filter(id=self.id).values('nombre'))
       codigo_generado = "".join(item[0].upper() for item in re.findall("\w+", curso_nombre)[:4])
    return self.codigo_generado

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Generacion automatica de Slug.
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.nombre)[:50]
        return super(cursos, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

        # Generacion automatica de curso
        if not self.codigo_curso:
           self.codigo_curso = self.crear_codigo()
        return super(cursos, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I try changing the order of the functions but still find that error which could not be the problem thanks

Answer (score 1):

The model manager is called via `objects`, not `object`:

```
curso_nombre = str(cursos.objects.filter(id=self.id).values('nombre'))
                          # HERE^
```

Comment: sorry for not seeing that error but also ahy one more thing but take longer function